# Redirect page if not logged in

Tags: velocity

How can you redirect the page if the user does not logged in in velocity machine? for example when you visit a another page it will redirect to login page to view the that another page, do I need a conditonal on that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using SpringFramework in your project.

You could simply add an interceptor to check whether the user has logged in or not and redirect him. You could also add a filter in web.xml file to do the same.

Comment: another question how can you create a conditional vm that can redirect with the same page when you logged in? like this `#if (link == "samelink")
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=unmoderated?accepted=U" /> 
#end`